# Macro passed symbols not values

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm working on a macro that unwraps a map of `{"string-name" 'some-val}` into a let binding. For instance:

```
(with-locals {"a" 4} (inc a))
; => 5
```

My current code works just fine in the above case:

```
(defmacro with-locals [m & body]
  `(let ~(into [] (mapcat (fn [[s v]] [(symbol s) v]) m))
    ~@body))

(macroexpand-1 '(with-locals {"a" 1} (inc a)))
; => (clojure.core/let [a 1] (inc a))
```

However, I run into issues when the map is not directly passed into the macro.

```
(let [local-vals {"a" 4}] (macroexpand-1 '(with-locals local-vals (inc a))))
; Syntax error macroexpanding with-locals at xxx.
; Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

What am I missing? Is it just not possible to make this macro the way I want, because they run at compile time?

Comment: The macroexpansion happens in compile time and local-vals is just a symbol, it does not have any value associated with it at the time.